# selecting some data within specific number of days

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on sales data and I want to know if Customer A purchased product X from more than one provider within 3 days and I'm working on only one date Claim Date

I Can't find T-Sql query for it 
for example

```
SELECT CusName,ProdName,ProvName
FROM table1 
WHERE [Claim Date] between Day([Claim Date]) and DATEADD (Day ,-3 , [Claim Date]
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and exepct result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `WHERE EXISTS` clause should do the job:

```
SELECT CusName,ProdName,ProvName
FROM table1 a
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM table1 b WHERE
  b.CusName=a.CusName AND 
  b.ProdName=a.ProdName AND
  b.ProvName!=a.ProvName AND
  ABS(DATEDIFF(day,a.ClaimDate,b.ClaimDate))<3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for that

```
SELECT t1.CusName,t1.ProdName,t1.ProvName,t2.ProvName
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 ON t1.CusName=t2.CusName AND t1.ProdName=t2.ProdName 
WHERE t1.ProvName!=t2.ProvName
    AND ABS(DATEDIFF(day,t1.ClaimDate,t2.ClaimDate)) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a having clause and a count of the providers:

```
SELECT CusName, COUNT(DISTINCT ProvName) Provider_count
FROM table1 
WHERE [Claim Date] between Day([Claim Date]) and DATEADD (Day ,-3 , [Claim Date] 
AND ProdName = 'X'
GROUP BY CusName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ProvName) > 1
```

Note, you do not need to include the count in the select clause, but you do need it in the having clause.